# How do I Animate a character in Unity3D (Animator)?

Tags: c#, unity

first of all, I am new to Programming and Unity, but I want to create a simple game with Unity3D. I am using the StandardAssets (character) where all animations are included, but I dont get how to change animation state.

In the beginning I used this simple c# script to move the player:

```
    //move the player
    //A/D / LEFT /RIGHT
    transform.Translate (Vector3.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    //FORWARD/BACKWARDS
    transform.Translate (Vector3.forward * Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

But then I was only able to move the player around without any animations.

In the "Animator I am using the standard Controller "ThirdPersonAnimatorController". 
But how can I interact with the Controller/Animator? The Condition to change from Idle to Walk is CharStateMove = 1. 
But How can I change this value? I thought of something like "CharStateMove++;"

Or is there a more easier way to animate a character? Because I dont want to spent the whole time on animate the character. A very simple Animation would be enaught for me...

Comment: I'm not voting to close because this has a different title that visitors might search for, but this is mostly a duplicate of http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/76260/unable-to-use-maya-animation-with-scripts-when-imported-to-unity/77409

Comment: There is a great video that unity themselves made about animating in unity here is the link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xx21y9eJq1U

Comment: Unity has tutorials. If you are new to unity you should go through them. This question is answered there.